# Would a coiled spring with more rings produce more force when pressed and then released?

Tags: spring

Suppose that you have 2 coiled springs. Both are equally tall, wide, and thick. One has more rings than the other; this means that one is longer than the other when made into a straight line.

Would the longer one produce more force when pressed all the way and then relased?

Answer (score 1):

All else being equal, the one with fewer rings will be stiffer.  The reason is that a given amount of compression of the spring corresponds to more bending of the wire when there are fewer coils.